# Keeping track of SocketID in NodeJs and Express

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

After playing around a bit i found out the hard way that the socket.io will change the socketId on a socket reconnection. That said i am looking into a way for my NodeJs to keep track of changes to the socketID. Socket has a build in store which keeps track of SocketId's , Remote addresses etc. How reliable is that store and can i query a socketID quickly by a UserID which i stored in that db ?
I also found some docs on that one can set its own SocketID which has to be unique but does this allow me to avoid to issue a new SocketID on refresh or is that still not possible.
Instead of SocketID, is there a way to send a message to a client based on a USERID  instead ?
If neither of the above work, i guess i will be back to drawing board and store session info in a DB table and update the data.

Many questions but hopefully someone can share some inside with me

Here is my SocketIO helper class i use

```
const io = require('socket.io');
class ioWrapper {

constructor(app, { middlewares, updateSession, clearSession } = {}) {
    this.io = io(app);
    this.connected = {};

    if (middlewares && middlewares.length) {
        for (const middleware of middlewares) {
            this.io.use(middleware);
        }
    }

    this.io.on('connect', client => {
        //put callback to constructor to update your session
        if (updateSession) {
            updateSession(client.id);
            console.log('Updated: ' + client.id)
        }
        client.jwt = client.id
        this.connected[client.id] = client;




        console.log('Connected: ' + client.id + '  ' )// + this.io.socket.request.connection.remoteAddress)

        client.on('disconnect', () => {
            if (clearSession) {
                clearSession(client.id);
            }
            if (this.connected[client.id]) {
                delete this.connected[client.id];
            }
            console.log('Disconnect: ' + client.id )
        });

        client.on('error', e => console.log(e));
        client.on('connect_error', e => console.log('connect_error', e));

    });

    this.ioEmit = this.ioEmit.bind(this);
    this.ioInject = this.ioInject.bind(this);
}
ioEmit(socketId, event) {
    try {
        if (this.connected[socketId]) {
            this.connected[socketId].emit(...event);
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
ioInject(socketId, handler) {
    try {
        if (this.connected[socketId]) {
            this.connected[socketId].on(...handler);
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
}

  module.exports = (app, middleware, updateSession) => new ioWrapper(app, middleware, updateSession);
```

Comment: What did you mean by a refresh? A socket re-connection or anything else?

Comment: I have a angular app and if the user hits refresh on the browser the socket gets disconnected and creates a new connection with a new socketid